# javascript cross domain GET method

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm trying to get an html content to an external url using ajax request and load it to specific div element but I'm having error by doing the cross domain ajax request

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://www.myowndomain.com/embed.php?c=5576b014b210a. (Reason:
>   CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

This is the sample code that must be pasted in any blogs, forum or website of a users (any domain):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://myowndomain.com/embed.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">embed.init(["5576b014b210a", "myembeded"]);embed.myCollage();</script><div id="myembeded"></div>
```

then here's the code for embed.js resided in my domain

```
var embed = embed || (function(){
    var _args = {};

    return {
        init : function(param) {
            _args = param;
        },
        myCollage : function() {
            embed.load_home(_args[0],_args[1]);
        },
        load_home:function (id,elementId) {
            var request = embed.createCORSRequest("get", "http://myowndomain.com/embed.php?c="+id);
            if (request){
                request.onload = function(){
                    document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = request.responseText;
                };
                request.send();
            }
        },
        createCORSRequest:function (method, url){
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            if ("withCredentials" in xhr){
                xhr.open(method, url, true);
            } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined"){
                xhr = new XDomainRequest();
                xhr.open(method, url);
            } else {
                xhr = null;
            }
            return xhr;
        }
    };
}());
```

and for the embed.php resided in my domain

```
if(isset($_GET['c'])){
    echo file_get_contents('http://myowndomain.com/embed/?u='.$_GET['c']);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already solved it. by adding this to my embed.js:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature implemented into browsers to prevent you from performing requests that aren't on your local domain.

If the other site has an API that allows that, then use their API. Otherwise you can't get the data. If it's your site, modify your web server to enable the requests by adding the header info.

This is all info that could have been gotten by just looking up the error yourself.

Comment: which part in the server? can i add it to my php code? can you give me sample header info? thanks